# android - Is merchant order number always same?

Tags: android, security, in-app-purchase, google-play

I'm building an android application that have an google play in-app purchase feature but I want to add some security in the server side to prevent hacker to generate random order number and sent it to my server but I don't know which part of the order number is always same. I've read this -> http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html and I've checked my application log and I assume that the number before the dot in order number is always same. For example in this order number example from android developer `"orderId" : "12999556515565155651.5565135565155651"` I think the 12999556515565155651 is always same. But I'm still not sure yet, is there any of you have a proof or another suggestion how to check which is the real order number or fake order number?

Thank You

Comment: You just do full setup and print this order id on console. I think after 5 dec-2012 google is adding your unique merchant account number here so it should be always same for your app.

Comment: @Ankit ah OK if you can find some link that can prove that please write it in the answer then I'll vote your answer and mark it :)